# Why can’t compojure-app and hiccup import function hiccup.form/form-to?

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, compojure, hiccup

I use "lein new compojure-app" to create a web project, hiccup has been already imported in project.clj:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
             [compojure "1.5.2"]
             [hiccup "1.0.5"]
```

and I can see the jar file

I use intellij for ide,in home.clj:

```
(ns ansible.routes.home
(:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
        [ansible.views.layout :as layout]
        [hiccup.form :refer :all]
        ))
```

but when write:

```
(form-to [ :post "/"]
```

intellij tells me `form-to can't be resolved`, if I use this:

```
[hiccup.form :as hf]
```

then write

```
(hf/
```

intellij tells me I can use function:group,input-filed,make-id,make-name,with-group,but no form-to,but form-to is a function in package hiccup.form

How do I fix this?

Comment: `org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"` and `compojure "1.5.2"` are pretty old releases. Try to use the most recent ones.

Comment: Thanks.I don't know why  "lein new compojure-app" will give me clojure 1.8 and compojure 1.5 by default,I have use clojure 1.10 and compojure 1.6.1 but the error is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, using `:require` with `:refer :all` is considered bad form, because it may shadow some functions without you noticing.

Check if any of the other namespaces you require in `home.clj` already has a function called `form-to`. Try using something like:

```
(ns myapp.routes.home
  (:require [compojure.core :as cc :refer [defroutes GET]]
            [myapp.views.layout :as layout]
            [hiccup.form :as hf]))

(defn home []
  (layout/common [:h1 "Hello World!"]))

(defroutes home-routes
  (GET "/" [] (home)))
```